# How can I initialize a guild in discord, c#?

Tags: c#, discord

```
IGuild guild;
IGuildUser user = guild.GetUserAsync(buffer,CacheMode.AllowDownload).Result;
```

I want guild to be the guild , the bot is on.How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
// The Id of the guild you want
ulong guildId = 123456789;

// Inject DiscordSocketClient through DI
var guild = _client.GetGuild(guildId);
```